# Rails sending constructor to script rather than variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to Rails and even newer to JavaScript, so bear with me.

It seems like Rails is sending a JQuery object's constructor to my script, rather than the value of the variable I'm giving it.

**_form.html.erb**

```
.....
<%= skill_form.check_box { id: "strength_checkbox_#{skill.id}" } %>
<%= render partial: 'proficiency_selector', locals: {strength_id: skill.id} %>
<%= javascript_tag("toggle_proficiency(#{skill.id});") %>
.....
```

**_proficiency_selector.html.erb**

```
<div id="proficiency_selector_<%= strength_id %>">
......
</div>
```

**toggle_proficiency.js**

```
$(function toggle_proficiency (strength_id) {
  alert(strength_id);
  .....
});
```

The proper skill.id is shown when I render it in the form, but the JavaScript alert is printing out the following:

```
function ( selector, context ) {

    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `<%= javascript_tag("toggle_proficiency(#{skill.id});") %>`

Comment: Same result but thanks for the cleaner code!

Comment: What is the type of **strength_id** you need in JS? Check if this helps: `javascript_tag("toggle_proficiency('#{skill.id}');")`. If you want it as integer only, then parse it in JS `parseInt(strength_id)`.

Comment: **strength_id** should be a string. Putting quotes around `#{skill.id}` returns [object Object] and performing `parseInt(strength_id)` returns NaN.

Comment: Ok, the problem is `$(function toggle_proficiency (strength_id) {
  alert(strength_id);
  .....
}`

Move it out of `$(` and define the function normally in **toggle_proficiency.js**

Comment: That does it! Thank you so much!